# iOS 8 changes not showing on iOS 7 devices

Tags: ios, ios7, web-applications, ios8, version

Hope you can help. I have made some basic styling (CSS) to my iOS webapp that look great in iOS  devices greater than 8.0 but if you view them in 7.0 for example the styling is off.

I have looked all over for user agent tips on configuring based on operating system and I can't seem to find anything to help me for this specifically.

Have any of you experienced this?

How can I remedy this?

Please help I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The problem was the top of the screen has a bar that removes 20px from the height and makes the height 300px instead of 320px (landscape). The updated phones with 8.0 and beyond do not have this bar and thus leave room for the changes since the height is now a true 320.

The best way to fix this is a conditional in JavaScript or if you use a CSS that offers conditionals.

This was for an iPhone 4 and iPhone 5, thus the reference to the 320px.